# How to do you solve an equation with two "equals" signs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm sorry for doing such a basic question, I just can't find confirmation if it works like i think it does.

How would you do an exercise like $\;\;x+2 = 6 = y+3\;\;$?

Comment: This means that all are equal, i.e., if $a = b = c$ then $a=b$, $b=c$, and $a=c$.

Comment: Why is this tagged "calculus"?

Comment: How do you think it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the following two equations :

$x+2=6$

$y+3 = 6$.

Solve for x, and for y.

Comment: Alright thanks i just wanted confirmation cause it seemed strange to me that it was that easy (I saw it on an exam and wasn't sure if that was the way to do it)

Comment: Well, you thought right!

Answer (score -1):

Two equals signs means that the first quantity is equal to the second quantity, and the second quantity is equal to the third quantity, or that all three quantities are equal. No surprises.

$x+2=6$, and $6=y+3$, so $x=4, y=2$.